# Font-size issue in iOS, invisible in Chrome developer tools

Tags: html, css, ios, google-chrome, mobile

On my site [stefaanoyen.be](https://stefaanoyen.be) I have an issue with a div in my footer.

This is the HTML:

```
<div class="right-div">
   <span class="footertips"><a href="https://www.stefaanoyen.be/category/blog">Krachttips</a> • </span>
   <a href="https://www.stefaanoyen.be/algemene-voorwaarden">Algemene voorwaarden</a> • 
   <a href="https://www.stefaanoyen.be/privacy">Privacy</a> • 
   <a style= "color:#b72518" href="https://www.stefaanoyen.be/contact/">Contacteer mij</a><
/div>
```

And this is the CSS:

```
.right-div {
    float: right;
    padding-right: 10px;
    font-size: 12px !important;
}
```

When I inspect my footer in Google Chrome developer tools, the right-div has a font size of 12px, also on iPhone width. However, when I look at my site in Chrome or Safari on my iPhone 8, the left-div has a font size of 12px, but the right-div has a bigger font size (the line that starts with 'Krachttips):

[image]

How come? I can't inspect the css on my iPhone and I have no idea where this is coming from.

Thank you so much for helping me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this css

```
body {
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
```

You need to have macosx device to debug follow those steps [Safari Develop Menu](https://support.apple.com/guide/safari/use-the-developer-tools-in-the-develop-menu-sfri20948/mac)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to give the span and a tags the font size style property and check if it is ok?